# Update DataGridView Control DataSource C# Win Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, bindingsource, bindinglist

I have a list of objects and I want to rebind DataGridView in every second. I tried many things, bindingsource, BindingList with INotifyPropertyChanged interface . They work great when you have static collection in your code, but I need to update datasource from database so, in this way I have to iterate each object and check if it is new or deleted and update BindingList, but it is solution. I prefer writing like this in every second:

```
BindingListObeject = new BindingList<MyObject>(ListOfMyObjects);
```

or

```
BindingListObeject.Clear();
//in loop
BindingListObeject.Add(new_object);
```

DataGridView will have scrolling and also selected cell must be selected after rebinding datasource.  And also grid should not flicker.

How can I manage that? I use EF to get my desired list of objects.

Comment: have you tried Suspend/ResumeLayout  to avoid flickering?

Comment: Yes, I tried, still flickering

Answer (score 1):

Try [ObservableCollection()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) or any other collection with CollectionChange event

And don't ever do something like **myCollection = ...anything...** thats make new object with new handle for myCollection, awhile your grid still binded to older handle. Just change collection, do not renew it.

Comment: It seems to work, but when I rebind gridview datasource grid rows are not effected as I see. For test I am removing items from my list and then rebind datasource, in view item is removed, everything is ok but grid rows are still same count, I will debug more and write my results here

Comment: I use, first remove one item from list, then set again datasource, then also DataGridView.refresh() but grid rows count doesn't reflect at all. I need to somehow update rows also at code side, in view item is removed. What is wrong?

Comment: It seems it is not an option, 

ObservableCollection<T> implements INotifyCollectionChanged, not IBindingList, and the DataGridView doesn't know about INotifyCollectionChanged. :( Any ideas? I want to use it in win forms again

Comment: So, you posted not enough code to understand concrete reason of you trouble. That can be several possible points where you did something wrong. Try to new post with more specific fragments of code around grid, collection, source of collection and (important, in code) how did you try to update your visual data on view

Comment: In my title I said that it was a win forms project, It seems it is impossible to rebind whole datasource without flickering  and losing scroll.  ObservableCollection almost worked.  I am not happy with the solution but I used BindingList, I just thought nothing was impossible, but Microsoft doesn't agree with me a guess :P Thank you for your time and help